# How do I wait until an element is visible with Protractor when Angular is not available?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have a login function that I'm using for a Protractor test, it looks like this:

```
var config = require("../helpers/config.js");

var login = function() {
    browser.driver.get(config.dsp.url);
    browser.driver.findElement(by.name("userName")).sendKeys(config.dsp.user);
    browser.driver.findElement(by.name("password")).sendKeys(config.dsp.password);
    return browser.driver.findElement(by.name("submit")).click().then(function() {
        return browser.driver.wait(function() {
            return browser.driver.isElementPresent(browser.driver.findElement(by.className("sample-class-name")));
        }, 360000);
    });
}

module.exports = login;
```

I can't use any of the protractor specific hooks because Angular is not used on this page, so I have to use the underlying webdriver API. The problem is, I can't seem to figure out how to wait until an element is visible using this wrapped webdriver object. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error I get when I run this test is TypeError: "Invalid Locator" for browser.driver.isElementPresent.

Comment: If Angular is not present, why don't you simply disable the sync with `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` ?

Comment: Good question. Angular is going to be present as soon as the login is complete. I just need to get the user past the non-angular login page.

Comment: You could disable the sync and then enable it once you're done with the page. Note that you'll have to schedule the assignment in the control flow.

Comment: That's the problem, I don't quite know when I'm done with the page because I can't figure out whether the element which tells me I am done is present.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with the expected conditions from the underlying driver:

```
var config = require("../helpers/config.js");
var until = require('selenium-webdriver').until;

var login = function() {
    var driver = browser.driver;

    driver.get(config.dsp.url);
    driver.findElement(by.name("userName")).sendKeys(config.dsp.user);
    driver.findElement(by.name("password")).sendKeys(config.dsp.password);
    driver.findElement(by.name("submit")).click();

    return driver.wait(until.elementLocated(by.css(".sample-class-name")), 10000)
      .then(e => driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(e)), 10000);
}

module.exports = login;
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Thank you, the same for me !

Comment: I have a same issue tried with above code but its not working for me.