# TypeError: Invalid Locator while using contains() in xpath

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I have a Invalid locator issue in my code. i have checked api and looks like its correct can someone look into my code ?.

```
var header = ".//h1[@class='flexgrid-col' and contains(text(),'Live Dev')]";
/* Verify Live Dev Headers */
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(driver.findElement(by.xpath(header)),10000)).then(function(){
    console.log(chalk.green("Header Verified"));
});
driver.quit();
```

Comment: i have checked with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40363269/how-do-i-wait-until-an-element-is-visible-with-protractor-when-angular-is-not-av but no luck

Comment: Please post the complete error message.

Comment: node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\by.js:275  throw new TypeError('Invalid locator'); 

 **TypeError: Invalid locator    at Object.check [as checkedLocator] **(C:\abc\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\by.js:275:9)    at Object.elementLocated (C:\abc\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\until.js:238:16)    
at Object.<anonymous>

Comment: Try to replace `text()` by `.`

Comment: tried. its not about xpath. its causing in until.element

Answer (score 0):

The *xpath* seems to be a bit off. You can try either of the following *xpaths*:

```
var header = "//h1[@class='flexgrid-col'][text()='Live Dev']";
```

or

```
var header = "//h1[@class='flexgrid-col'][contains(.,'Live Dev')]";
```

or

```
var header = "//h1[@class='flexgrid-col'][normalize-space()='Live Dev']";
```