# Unable to click checkbox input element but can read its value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

In my protractor test the statement

```
await element(by.model('publishCtrl.isPublishedInAllRegions')) .click();
```

fails saying "ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible"

even though the previous assertion that I added to debug this

```
expect(await element(by.model('publishCtrl.isPublishedInAllRegions')).isPresent())
    .toBeTruthy();
```

is working. Why is this happening? Also if I don't write this assertion, then the later assertion for reading the checkbox value works:

```
expect(await element(by.model('publishCtrl.isPublishedInAllRegions'))
        .getAttribute('value'))
 .toBeTruthy();
```

The checkbox definition along with its parent element is

```
<label ng-transclude="" pan-form-option-type="checkbox" class="p6n-checkbox p6n-checkbox-label">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="publishCtrl.isPublishedInAllRegions" ng-click="publishCtrl.toggleAllRegionsSelection()" ng-required="!publishCtrl.publishedRegionsCount" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-valid-required" jslog="47386;track:generic_click" aria-invalid="false">
  <span class="p6n-form-label" ng-transclude=""> All regions </span> 
</label>
```

Comment: you need that extra `.publishAllRegionsCheckboxInput` for click?? `element(by.model('publishCtrl.isPublishedInAllRegions')).click()` doesn't work? what is `publishAllRegionsCheckboxInput`?

Comment: The fact that element is present in DOM doesn't really mean that this element is visible, so there is nothing weird here. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40363269/how-do-i-wait-until-an-element-is-visible-with-protractor-when-angular-is-not-av) might be helpful

Comment: you need to write a test which checks the visibility of your element rather than the existence

Comment: Ashish Ranjan, now I have removed the extra publishAllRegionsCheckboxInput. In my real code I use a helper function publishAllRegionsCheckboxInput and messed up while replacing it for the stackoverflow question.

Comment: Please share the parent dom of input that is most important. Add pareht html tag of the input tag and sibiling if there is?

Comment: Is your input tag is under any label tag?

Comment: Yes it is under a label tag, I have pasted the dom of its parent towards the end of my question .

Answer (score 0):

Here the input tag may have zero height, it literally means not visible. But it is present in DOM and you are able to interact.

Here we have to click the label which is holding input tag instead of the clicking the input tag.

You cannot click this `by.modal('modalvalue')` of protactor js which inturn will access element with css locator as `[ng-model='publishCtrl.isPublishedInAllRegions']`. This return the input button not the label

To find the value with ng-modal which is unique in angular, we can write xpath like,

```
  await  element(by.xpath("//a[@ng-modal='publishCtrl.isPublishedInAllRegions']/parent::label")).click()
```

But I also see the ng-click is configured only to input tag, which simulate onclick. Please try above suggestion and add your comment.

If not works, click anchor directly by executing javascript using javascript executor as it is not visible.

```
var element =element(by.xpath("//a[@ng-modal='publishCtrl.isPublishedInAllRegions']");
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click()",element);
```

or simple with jquery dirertly

```
browser.executeScript("$(\"input[ng-modal='publishCtrl.isPublishedInAllRegions'])\").click()",element);
```

Comment: I tried your xpath but it fails with NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(xpath, //a[@ng-model='publishCtrl.isPublishedInAllRegions']/parent::label)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to click radio/checkbox buttons input element is with javascript executor. He does not care if element is not clickable or other state.

Or you can normally click the label/span element that is wrapped inside input element.

Here is an example:

JS click:

```
export async function jsClickButton(button: ElementFinder) {

    try {
        return await browser.executeScript('arguments[0].click()', button).then(async() => {
            console.log('Element has been clicked.');
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Element could not be clicked', error);
    }
}
```

Or normal click (in your case).

```
await  element(by.xpath('//input[@ng-model=\'publishCtrl.isPublishedInAllRegions\']/following-sibling::span')).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
await element(by.css('input[type="checkbox"]')) .click();
```

And for assertion

```
  expect(await element(by.css('input[type="checkbox"]')).getAttribute('value').isDisplayed().then((value: boolean) =>{
    expect(value).toBe(true);
    });
```

Hope the above answers help you. Try using css for finding elements. It is recommended for protractor.